# Add Document link in 2010 document libraries behaviour

Tags: document-library, content-type

I have created a new document library in moss 2010 and assigned a content type. When I choose the document ribbon tab and select new, I see the content type in the drop down for selection. If I however use the add document link that is displayed below the list of documents, it gives me a standard file upload dialog, rather than my content type form.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to configure this correctly?

All the best

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have it configured correctly.  The "Add Document" link is the equivalent of the "Upload Document" button in the ribbon.  I'm not sure why it is called two different things.  The only place to add a new document based on your content type is in the ribbon where you found it.  I wish it were a tad more intuitive myself.